# Is there a way to speed up animations by only animating whatever is in view?

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I have a lot of objects and bones in my scene. It's extremely inefficient to have to turn all of them off and on in the outlier just to simply preview a tiny part of the animation at a reasonable, common frame-rate. I don't have any unnecessary modifiers, I already enabled frame dropping, they had no almost no effect. The frame rate only increases as I hide objects.

Can't blender simply only render the animation of whatever is in view at a particular angle like that subdivision surface optimization?

Comment: You can't place elements/objects in different layers (or eqivalent in 2.8) and just don't include the unwanted layers until the final render?

Comment: Nope because they're individual bones and vertex groups. The only way I see is to go in the outlier and disable them.